# How can i update or create redirect uri in GCP(Google Cloud Platform) use googleapis

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I implement add, update, delete redirect URI in GCP Oauth2.0 client ID.
I find out useful library is googleapis, Unfortunately i couldn't update, create ur in GCP
Please how to update redirect uri in GCP use API..
I develop in nextjs,

I did research service api in google cloud  document, but can't found

Clients object  in googleapi library doesn't contain update, create method